# Website CSS & JavaScript slow to update

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've connected to my server via FTP using Visual Studio 2013, and whenever I make changes to my .js or .css files, it takes up to several minutes for my website to update in the browser (same in Chrome, Firefox and IE). Interestingly, my regular HTML code updates instantly.

This is not a cache issue, as I have the "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" option enabled in Chrome. I have also tried using PHP to add a random timestamp when loading the files, as such:

```
    <script src="js/site.js?t=<?= time();?>"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css?t=<?= time();?>">
```

However, simply opening the .js or .css in a new tab reveals that the contents still aren't updated, even though they are in Visual Studio.

Is this a host issue, Visual Studio bug or something with my browsers?

Comment: opening them in a new tab loads the same cached copy as the page will fetch. [CTRL]+[F5] will pull up a new copy if it's available

Comment: @dandavis Ctrl+F5 still shows the old file. I'm convinced this isn't a cache issue.

Comment: do they update right away if you manually copy the files to the server using an FTP util?

Comment: @dandavis Using FileZilla and NotePad++ gives the same results. It's almost as if the host is sending an old version of my site to the browser, rather than the one currently stored on the server. Is this common practice?

Comment: no, that's not common, and nothing in your described pipeline indicates that behavior. you might have something like varnish in front of the server, the server might just be really really busy, or there are other complications not apparent now.

Comment: Your host or possibly your internet service provider may have an appliance which is doing caching.

Comment: Another website I have (on a paid host, unlike this one) updates the JavaScript and CSS instantly. However, if this is the reason, I still find it odd that the HTML updates immediately while the rest don't.

Comment: If you are using a CDN or if there is a cache mechanism on the server, it could be possible that it's considering the HTML to be dynamic, thus providing fresh files, and considering the CSS and Javascript to be static, thus delivering cached versions of those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out to be a host feature and I turned it off by entering this at the top of my .htaccess:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer your question, +1 for you :)